# Se puede consumir la información de una pagina .txt

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, axios

Tengo esta pagina: https://gitlab.com/d2945/words/-/raw/main/words.txt

Pero nunca e consumido un servicio o no se si sea posible obtener los datos de una pagina .txt

uso axios de nodejs

y si puedo obtenerla quiero pasarla a un array toda esa data. No me preocupa tanto pasarlo a un array ya que es facil, lo que me importa es poder consumirla

Comment: async function GetData(){
  return fetch("https://gitlab.com/d2945/words/-/raw/main/words.txt")
   .then(a=> a.text());
}

Comment: vale muchas gracias. Me sirvio tal cual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `text()` del [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), te permite traer como un texto desde una URL

```
async function GetData(){ 
  return 
   fetch("gitlab.com/d2945/words/-/raw/main/words.txt") 
    .then(a=> a.text()); 
}
```

Para retornar un Array, podría ser algo así:

```
async function GetData(){ 
  return 
   fetch("gitlab.com/d2945/words/-/raw/main/words.txt") 
    .then(a=> a.text().split('\n')); 
}
```